# CakePHP beforeSave & HABTM

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-model

I'm trying to write some beforeSave logic in CakePHP 2.0 beta. Basically I want the user to be able to submit some text for tag-like functionality. The beforeSave function would search a related table, if the tag exists just link it to the primary record, and if not, create the new tag & then link it.

So here's my function (in beforeSave):

```
function beforeSave() {
    if(!empty($this->data['Term']) && isset($this->Term)){
       $terms = $this->Term->find('list');
       $terms = array_flip($terms);

       foreach($this->data['Term'] as $key => $term){
           if(!empty($terms[$term['name']])){
               $this->data['Term']['Term'][$key]['id'] = $terms[$term['name']];
               unset($this->data['Term'][$key]);
           }else{
               $this->Term->create();
               $this->Term->save(array('Term' => array('name' => $term['name'])));
               $this->data['Term']['Term'][$key]['id'] = $this->Term->id;
               unset($this->data['Term'][$key]);
           }
       }
   }

   return true;
}
```

This basically works the way I want, creating records where necessary and finding the existing records, creating an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [Project] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Project Title
            ...
        )

    [Term] => Array
        (
            [Term] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

It also successfully saves the data in the primary model (Project). But the associations under [Term][Term] are ignored. I'm pretty sure this is the correct array structure to save HABTM associations.

Anyone see what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the view you should have 1 input text `$form->input('terms');` so the user can enter all the tags. So in beforeSave, you would have a string of the tags (or terms), you might want to slice it out to array, find('list') of the terms, and some array intersect or something. But in the end, you need the data to look something like this to use saveAll:

> ```
> Array
> (
> [Project] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 2
>         [title] => Project Title
>         ...
>     )
> [Term] => Array
>     (
>         [Term] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => 10 // id of the tag
>                 [1] => 2
>             )
>     )
> ```
>
> )

Comment: I'm not actually using form helper, but the fields look like this: `<input type="text" id="Term0Name" name="data[Term][0][name]" value="">`

Comment: PS this is why I'm not using form helper: http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/cdf1aaf3fe350695

Comment: you don't have to loop (The example in cake book doesn't have loop). Maybe because you did that, the data wasn't saved.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain what I'm doing very well, but the loop is to convert text in the input (the name of the tag) into an ID before saving, so that theoretically it would work with Cake's default save() function, which expects IDs

Comment: I was talking about the loop in google groups link, not the one in beforeSave(). But I did miss your point of new Term (or is it Tag?). Anyway, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you! It was the fact that I was putting the id into an array, when it should have just been an int. For the loop, what I'm trying to accomplish is having separate auto-complete text fields that can be used for a HABTM relationship, rather than select elements. For my use-case, I think it's better for usability.

Comment: this is my fav way of doing auto-complete field (integrate well with multiple select): http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html